# How should you use C++14 shared mutex with lambda captures and multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, lambda, c++14, mutex

I have some very simple code which is supposed to test a multi-threaded logger by starting 10 threads at the same time which will all write to the logger at once.

I expect to see all 10 messages, not in any order; However, I randomly get 5,6,7,8,9, and sometimes 10 output messages.

Here is the code:

```
//*.cxx
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex> // requires c++14
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

namespace {
    std::mutex g_msgLock;
    std::shared_timed_mutex g_testingLock;
}

void info(const char * msg) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(g_msgLock);
    std::cout << msg << '\n'; // don't flush
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    info("Start message..");

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    unsigned int threadCount = 10;
    threads.reserve(threadCount);

    { // Scope for locking all threads
        std::lock_guard<std::shared_timed_mutex> lockAllThreads(g_testingLock); // RAII (scoped) lock

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
            // Here we start the threads using lambdas
            threads.push_back(std::thread([&, i](){
                // Here we block and wait on lockAllThreads
                std::shared_lock<std::shared_timed_mutex> threadLock(g_testingLock);
                std::string msg = std::string("THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: ") + std::to_string(i);
                info(msg.c_str());
                }));
        }

    } // End of scope, lock is released, all threads continue now

    for(auto& thread : threads){
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

The output is generally something of the form:

```
Start message..
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 9
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 5
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 3
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 1
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 4
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 0
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 8
THREADED_TEST_INFO_MESSAGE: 7
```

Notice that there are only 8 outputs for this run.

Comment: For what it's worth, can't reproduce. I always see 10 messages printed.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for trying! What compiler did you use? This link should reproduce: http://cpp.sh/9cto5

Comment: Three of them: [clang](http://rextester.com/XHIUL41857), [GCC](http://rextester.com/MEFA61665), [MSVC](http://rextester.com/OKF47288)

Comment: I've used MSVC and GCC and I see this same behavior, since it seems like a race condition I wonder if your hardware for some reason just doesn't demonstrate the failure. When I use MSVC I get something like 2-5 messages out, but with GCC I get 5-10 messages.

Comment: Don't see any data to race for here.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, this problem was associated with my build system which was dropping messages. The executable is always producing the outputs as expected.